# Naive Bayes classifier for multiple outcomes and online learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics

I have used SKLearn's Naive Bayes to classify data into a partition. Now I want to use it to predict multiple outcomes that are not in a partition, such as multiple hashtags in a tweet. I read [this paper] and [this paper](https://portfolios.cs.earlham.edu/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/dipesh_CS488_paper.pdf) and they suggest Naive Bayes is competitive with k-nearest neighbors and TF-IDF.

SKLearn's [Multinomial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB) or [Bernoulli](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB) deal only with a single outcome, with a `y` vector of shape `(n_samples,)`:

```
 fit(X, y, sample_weight=None)[source]

    Fit Naive Bayes classifier according to X, y.

    Parameters:

        X: {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)

            Training vectors, where n_samples is the number of samples and n_features is the number of features.
        y: array-like of shape (n_samples,)

            Target values.
        sample_weight: array-like of shape (n_samples,), default=None

            Weights applied to individual samples (1. for unweighted).
```

So I need a different algorithm that takes an input `y, (n_samples, n_outcomes)`. Ideally, I would also like an algorithm that does "online learning", meaning that it can update its state when receiving a new tweet or a new hashtag, similar to the ["out-of-core" model fitting](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html#out-of-core-naive-bayes-model-fitting).

I searched online and didn't find a standard package. I found a [masters' thesis](https://github.com/daviesjamie/3yp/blob/master/server/classifier.py) that implements something similar and that is no longer maintained.

Does a standard Python package implement multi-outcome online learning Naive Bayes?